# Multipe relationships in Rails where the class name does not match the association name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a private message model that relates to two users, how do I setup an association so that PM.sender is the sender's user model and PM.receiver is recipient's user model? (so that I can call PM.sender.username etc.)

I have a sender_id and receiver_id field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming model classes `Message` and `User`, in your `Message` model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User'
end
```

Because the class name can't be deduced from the association name the explicit `:class_name` is required.

**Update:** Having just checked, the `:foreign_key` parameter shouldn't be required as long as the name of the foreign key is the name of the association followed by `_id`, which it is in this case.