# How to implement Rails associations when using roles instead of multiple models for user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations, roles, cancan

I need some advice on the best approach to take for the following.

I used to have Tutor, Student, Reservation models in my application.

I want a reservation to contain a Tutor and a Student.

Currently I am using devise for the user authentication, and I like the idea of using a generic User, and having roles defined for the users as many people have done with devise & cancan. It makes it easy to create an admin role for example.
Thus I could have a role Tutor or Student contained within User.

Now my problem is that I can no longer use associations in the way I would like, e.g.

```
Reservation
  belongs_to :Tutor
  belongs_to :Student
```

because I no longer have an individual model for each type of user.

What should I do?

I found that if I have individual models for Tutor and Student then in devise I would need seperate links for logging in and editing each type of user.

**Adding some links to similar questions**

[Multipe relationships in Rails where the class name does not match the association name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988915/multipe-relationships-in-rails-where-the-class-name-does-not-match-the-associati)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the class name to use 'User':

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tutor, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :student, :class_name => "User"
end
```

Comment: I have tried that suggestion just now. But while if I try Reservation.find(7).student I am getting an error NoMethodError: undefined method 'student'

Comment: Can you verify that you have a :student_id field on the :reservations table?  Also, are you using standard rails models directly, or a plugin that requires class hooks, like spree?

Comment: yes the field exists and is being populated by me. When i create the reservation I set it as follows '@reservation.student = current_user'
then I can access the id using the following 'Reservation.find(9).student_id' 
but 'Reservation.find(9).student' does not work.

Comment: And is the 'belongs_to' code in the reservation.rb file in the app/models directory?  I'm only asking because a NoMethod error would infer that the 'belongs_to' statement is not being called.

Comment: yes I've just confirmed thats where it is. not sure whats going wrong. Is there a site like jsFiddle where people can test code snippets?

Comment: Ah Jaysus... I just did a db:reset and restarted the server and console and now it appears to be working fine! My bad, I guess it was restarting rails that did the trick. Thanks a million for your help.

Comment: @RailsFan What would the model for the User class look like for this one ?, do we have to include has_one/has_many :tutor,:student in the Users class ?

Comment: @codeObserver: RailsFan is treating 'tutor' and 'student' as roles, not as full fledged model objects.  Role assignment can be as simple as a text field or a binary flag - there are many ways to do this that don't involve associating a separate model.  See [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/189-embedded-association) for another interesting approach.

Comment: @PinnyM Thanks for the reply. So My User class should have some indication that its involved in an association from the Reservation class . Should I add :has_many :Reservations in the User class to complete the association ?

Comment: @codeObserver: the User model would probably need 2 `has_many` associations - one on `student_id`, and one on `tutor_id` - and they should be named them accordingly

Comment: so the foreign key column on the reservation table would be student_id and tutor_id instead of user_id and that would be understood by the framework ? .

Comment: also do I need to add tutor_id, student_id columns on the user table ?